# Cisco BGP - see communities on advertised-routes?

Tags: cisco, bgp

We have an outbound route-map on an eBGP peer that adds some communities to certain prefixes. Is there any way to prove that this is actually happening from the sender side in classic IOS?

`show ip bgp neighbor x.x.x.x advertised-routes` does not show them

Even `debug ip bgp update out` doesn't seem to!

In gns3 I can make the same config and see that it works from my fake upstream side, but I need to be able to verify in the production router from the local side...

Comment: I'm sure you do, but I'll ask anyway: you have "send-community" on the neighbour right?

Comment: Oh, sure. As I said - it works in GNS3 and I'm pretty certain it's working in production. I'm just looking for a way to SHOW that it's working from the sender side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last time I checked/tried to do this, it wasn't possible in IOS. I'm not sure about NX-OS or IOS-XE/XR though. It doesn't help you, but this is possible to do on Juniper gear.

Regarding your configuration - make sure you're using the `additive` keyword in your route-maps to set the communities, otherwise you will not be adding communities to the list, but rather replacing any existing communities with the one you're setting in your route-maps.

Comment: Thanks - I found that Juniper command, teasing me! This is classic IOS, unfortunately. It seems that nothing short of packet capture will show me what my updates look like *after* the outbound route-map is applied (communities, modified next-hops or anything else).

Answer (score 2):

Set  up another BGP  peer  or  route-reflector   that  you  control with identical  policies .   Of  course,  make sure you're not blackholing  any traffic  toward this peer.

Comment: As I said, it works in GNS3. It was specifically to _see_ the communities on *that* session on *that* router. I was having a fight with a supplier who insisted (without checking the results) that my config could _never_ work because it didn't exactly match their sample config. Since then, we've proved that they had a config issue on their side, but being able to do "show ip bgp neigh x.x.x.x advertised-routes detail" would have saved some hassle.

Answer (score 1):

On router running IOS-XR you can use "show bgp advertised neighbor A.B.C.D or X:X::X",
it will give you additional info about the prefixes sent to the neighbor
(including of course community if configured).
As stated before remeber to use the "additive" keyword inside the route-map statement if you don't want to replace the whole list
and add the "send-community-ebgp" under the right address-family in order
to start sending it to the neighbor

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully confirm BGP attributes are being applied by debugging BGP and then resetting the peer and then watching the debug messages - It is of course disruptive. After you did your debug ip bgp update-out, did you do a hard reset on the peer? I will lab this up and provide a screenshot.

Comment: You shouldn't need to drop the session... do a soft bgp clear out

Comment: Well, when I tried with `debug ip bgp update out` I saw the updates but that didn't include the communities. If I do `debug ip bgp update` to see the incoming updates on my GNS3 lab, then I _do_ see the community in the incoming update debug messages, but that's no use to me in the real situation.

Comment: Which IOS version does this for you? My lab is a relatively old 12.4T, now that I think about it. It's possible this has been added in 15+ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run 
**show ip bgp x.y.z.0/24**  ?
That command shows Community in our environment (15.+ version)

Comment: That shows the community for the received prefix though, doesn't it? Not the sent one (if it is added with a route-map)...

Answer (score 0):

This works on **IOS-XE 15.x**:

> show bgp ipv4 unicast detail

It produces this output:

```
BGP routing table entry for 0.0.0.0/0, version 5
  Paths: (1 available, best #1, table default, not advertised to EBGP peer)
  Not advertised to any peer
  Refresh Epoch 1
  65000 65001
    1.1.1.1 from 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1)
      Origin IGP, localpref 100, valid, external, best
      Community: no-export
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0x0
```